# Create hyperlink using XSLT which open xml file on the file system

Tags: xml, xslt, hyperlink

I need to add hyperlink to XSL file that I write. This hyperlink must open a XML file through a user click event. These files XML are on my local file system into my current directory.

a part of the XML document

```
<Document>
<racine> <label>Jdk from Sun</label> </racine>
<racine> <label>Maven plugin Eclipse</label>  </racine>
</Document>
```

For this part of my document, there are two files XML into the working directory namely 'Jdk from Sun.XML' and 'Maven plugin Eclipse'

a part of XSL that I have written

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" cdata-section-elements="Cdata" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match = "/">

<html> 
  <head/>
  <Body>
   <xsl:for-each select="Document/racine">
   <html><a href="<H3><xsl:value-of select="label"/></H3>"</a></html>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </Body>
<html>
```

My expression

```
<html><a href="<H3><xsl:value-of select="label"/></H3>"</a></html>
```

is a nonsense, I know but I don't know how to act for the best. For being more precise, I use href attribute to link to the local filesystem to 'Jdk from Sun.xml' and 'Jdk from Sun.xml' files.
Your help is very precious. 
Thank in advance

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking, but you can always use the `file://` protocol in your `href` attribute to link to the local filesystem.

Comment: Yes, it is what I want. But I don't know how to use that. That's why I need your help! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution about my issue. I share with people who could meet that.

For the following XML file

```
<Document>
 <racine> <label>Jdk from Sun</label> </racine>
 <racine> <label>Maven plugin Eclipse</label>  </racine>
</Document>
```

and this part of XSL

```
<xsl:element name="a">
  <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="label" />
  <xsl:text>.xml</xsl:text>       
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="label" />
</xsl:element>
```

Look output in the screenshot above.[image]

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `<a href="<H3>...</H3>"></a>` is supposed to mean, so I assume you want something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Document">
    <html> 
      <head/>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="racine" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="racine">
    <h3>
      <a href="{encode-for-uri(label)}"><xsl:value-of select="label" /></a>
    </h3>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylsheet>
```

Note

- the use of template matching (`<xsl:apply-templates>` / `<xsl:template>`) over `<xsl:for-each>`
- the use of an *attribute value template* (the curly braces) to fill the `href` attribute
- the necessary use of `encode-for-uri()` ([docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-encode-for-uri)) to create a well-formed URL

Comment: Using your XSL, no link to 'Jdk from Sun.xml' or 'Jdk from Sun.xml' is available from the browser IE .IE is just showing "Jdk from Sun Maven plugin Eclipse". For being more precise, I use href attribute to link to the local filesystem to 'Jdk from Sun.xml' and 'Jdk from Sun.xml' files. Thanks

Comment: Then this is not an XSLT question but a rather basic HTML question. Figuring out how to create working links should not take you more than half an hour of reading.

Comment: I know how to create a link in HTML, no problem. My problem is to create that inside a XSL file. Sorry because as I'm new at XSL, that's why I have posted my question here. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. If you know how the link should look like then where is the issue?

Comment: Tag named 'a' represents link elements in HTML. But <a href="{encode-for-uri(label)}"><xsl:value-of select="label" /></a> doesn't appear the element label retrieved from the XML document as a link in display. I'm so Sorry, my english is not perfect!

Comment: You should show your actual input and your expected output. Otherwise all I can do is guess, and that's not a basis to work on.